# Trying to build OSRM: Could NOT find OSMPBF

Tags: ubuntu, open-source-routing-machine

I am trying to build OSRM on a Ubuntu system (14.04 LTS, up-to-date, 64 bit), but I am getting a "Could NOT find OSMPBF" error.

First I followed the Ubuntu 14.04 instructions on the [Building on Ubuntu](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Building-on-Ubuntu) page. This appears to have installed everything successfully.
Next I followed it with the [General Build Instructions](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Building-OSRM):

```
git clone https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend.git
cd osrm-backend
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

This fails at the `cmake` line with:

```
-- Building on a 64 bit system
-- Configuring OSRM in release mode
-- LTO working
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   date_time
--   filesystem
--   iostreams
--   program_options
--   regex
--   system
--   thread
--   unit_test_framework
-- Found Intel TBB
-- Looking for Luabind...
-- Found Luabind: /usr/lib/libluabind.so
-- Looking for LuaJIT 5.2
-- Could NOT find LUAJIT (missing:  LUAJIT_LIBRARIES) 
-- Performing Test LUABIND_WORKS
-- Performing Test LUABIND_WORKS - Success
-- Luabind/Lua5.2 combination working with /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.so
-- Looking for STXXL...
-- Found STXXL: /usr/lib/libstxxl.so
-- OpenMP support found. Linking just in case for stxxl
-- Looking for OSMPBF...
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find OSMPBF (missing: OSMPBF_LIBRARY OSMPBF_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindOSMPBF.cmake:46 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:283 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/richard/osrm/osrm-backend/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/richard/osrm/osrm-backend/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I can post the logs if necessary: CMakeError.log has a sequence of errors including `undefined reference to pthread_create` (doesn't appear to be related?)
CMakeOutput.log is much bigger, but the last build command reported is

```
Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec3258574548/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3258574548.dir/build.make CMakeFiles
/cmTryCompileExec3258574548.dir/build
```

...and it appears to have been successful.

Can anyone see what my problem is? Or where I should look? OSRM is new to me (hence my attempt to install & build, so that I can experiment with it), so I am not sure how OSMPBF fits in, or where to look. Also this Linux box has not been used for C++ dev work before, so it is possible a common tool might be missing? (I usually use Linux for Python dev). However the first step from *Building on Ubuntu* should have installed all the extras (cmake, boost, etc).

Comment: Before anyone says this is off-topic, OSRM build quiestions have been answered before, eg: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78728/min-function-not-found-compiling-osrm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same problem - instructions on [OSRM github](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Building-on-Ubuntu) are incomplete.
I've fixed it by:

```
sudo apt-get install libosmpbf-dev
```

Comment: Thanks - that pushes me further forward - now I'm getting an error from CMake that PROTOBUF_LIBRARY has been set to NOTFOUND

Comment: Try to find required libraries here: [osrm-installation](http://lxer.eu/scripts/osrm-installation/)
It looks like you need to install "libprotobuf-dev"

Comment: Thanks, yes that has fixed it. Now appears to have built okay. Still early in the learning curve here, but I think OSRM shows a lot of promise. If it lives up to that promise I hope to be eventually a part of the community/dev team...

Answer (score 2):

You try to use the unstable version from the develop branch. We recently removed the dependency for OSMPBF.

Comment: Perhaps the instructions should give links to both the latest stable and the dev branches?